# iPhone connect to internet over WiFi using PPPoE

Tags: iphone, wifi

Is there a way to connect my iPhone 4S to the Internet with WiFi when the connection is using the PPPoE protocol?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean *to connect to the wireless router* itself and get internet access this way?

According to Apple Support Forums,

> Generally people will have a router establish the PPPoE connection and then share it with the devices on the local network.

Do you have a computer or another device already connected to the local network? If so, you might be able to share the connection off one of these devices as a separate Wi-Fi connection.

Comment: I would like the connect to the wireless router and then start connection to the internet using a pppoe username/password. I cannot change the settings of my router as it is blocked by the provider. Sharing the pppoe connection wirelessly from my macbook doesnt seem to work as I cannot share a (wireless) pppoe using the "sharing" part of the settings.

Answer (score -2):

You could try using Connectify to redistribute the computer's connection over WiFi, not sure if it works on OS X though, check it out: google connectify.

Comment: Thanks for this tip. Was more looking for a homebrew iphone app to not be needing to use a laptop. This sharing tool might work; havent checked it yet. Question for me can be closed, have new internet connection without pppoe

Comment: Connectify is, unfortunately, Windows-only.